# Is it safe to use a link to an image in my AWS S3 bucket on my webpage?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an image in my AWS S3 bucket. Is it safe to include this image in my website by placing the AWS URL in an `<img>` tag? The URL includes parameters such as "Amz-Signature", "Amz-Credential", and "amz-security-token. Could these be used maliciously to get to access other files in my S3 bucket?

Here is an example URL:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucketName/FileName.jpg?X-Amz-Date=20160126T141139Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Signature=Lots_of_letters_and_Numbers2&X-Amz-Credential=MYAMAZON_CREDENTIALS/20160126/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=Host&x-amz-security-token=REALLY_LONG_SECURITYTOKEN
```

Alternatively, I can generate an expiry URL from my C# code using the AWS SDK. Something like:

```
var expiryUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSBucketName"],
    Key = fileName,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3)
};
```

This yields a URL that has "AWSAccessKeyId" as a parameter.

Are either of these URL's safe to use in my webpage? What risks would be involved in using them on my site?

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if you need additional information or if I am being unclear.

EDIT: To provide some further insight into my application, users are uploading a file to an S3 bucket. I'm using SignalR to confirm that the image is in the bucket by displaying the image from S3 on my webpage for the user to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not make the bucket public. If you do, then potentially user1 could see user2's uploaded files.

You can allow users to retrieve single files for a specific period of time using pre-signed URLs.

1. Mark the S3 bucket as private.
2. Use `GetPreSignedUrlRequest` to generate a pre-signed URL for the file you want the user to download.
3. Use that URL in your `<img>` tag.

Using this technique is safe:

1. The user can only download the file during the timeframe that you permit, until the expiration date (which you set as part of the `GetPreSignedUrlRequest` call)
2. The credentials you see in the URL are may be the same as those that were used to create the URL. But they are safe to show the user.
3. The user cannot download any other files from the bucket.

The URL uses a hashing technique to ensure the URL cannot be modified, nor can it be abused to get other files.

If displaying the access key ID is a concern, you can either (a) create an IAM user specifically for the purpose of downloading the files from S3, or (b) use an IAM role on your EC2 instance to generate the pre-signed URL.

References:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, when I use the `GetPreSignedUrlRequest`, it returns a url with `AWSAccessKeyId=` and `Signature=` parameters. Is it safe to give users to this information?

Comment: that's the way pre-signed urls work, the AWSAccessKeyId is a temporary one, and the Signature is the way to ensure the URL cannot be modified. You can definitely go with this

Comment: Yes it's safe as I mentioned in item #2 under "Using this technique is safe".

Comment: also note that you can also use pre-signed urls to upload: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html . I have never used in that way though

Comment: @Tom have you done this before and received URLs with different AWSAccessKeyIds from the `GetPreSignedUrlRequest? All of my URLs have the same AWSAccessKeyID. It matches the one I provided in the web.config under `appSettings`. You mentioned that this id is temporary but mine does not appear to be temporary. Could there be something I am doing incorrectly? Thank you.

Comment: yes I did this several time but using python boto3 package. I am not a c# dev, but if you do have the same access key as the one generated for your IAM user in AWS then sth must be wrong in your generation indeed (The temporary access key generated in the url usually begins with "ASIAI", when the classical access key begins with "AKIAI")

Comment: Ok thank you I will look into this. My key begins with "AKAI". I will see if there is something else I should specify when I get the pre-signed URL that gives me a temporary key. I am currently using the code posted in my question. Also, sorry for messing up the format in my previous comment.

Comment: actually I just double checked (i use 2 different ways to generate my urls), and using boto3 actually uses my real IAM access key. But since this is an IAM user dedicated to download from S3 and that you can't get my secret key, this is still safe and you are using the right way. I confirm that you can go with this

Comment: just in case, if you are interested (as it is a bit off-topic here), the second way I use to create signed urls is from the console by clicking "download" on items and copy/pasting the generated link. This can't be automated but is useful when you only need to quickly share a given file

Comment: The credentials in the URL may be the same as the access key used to generate the temporary URL. However, only the access key portion is included and is still safe. If this is still a concern, then (as Tom mentions), you can create an IAM credential dedicated for the purpose of downloading from S3. I will update my answer to reflect all this.

Comment: @Tom and Matt, thank you very much for clarifying. I have never used IAM before but I will look into setting that up. In the meantime, it sounds like this solution will work. User's would not be able to use my AWSAcessKeyID for anything so long as they do not have AWSSecretKey correct?

Comment: @MattHouser and @Tom thanks again for all the help. Is my goal here to create a new security credential [like this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-iam-create-creds.html)? So then that AWSAccessKey will be only associated with the specific app I'm linking to these images in? How do I get this new AWSAccessKey in my URL when I create it from `GetPreSignedUrlRequest`? Thank you for your patience. I have been struggling to understand this part.

Comment: The generated url will use the same credentials as those used to generate the url. So load your s3 client with the credentials before generating the url.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two ways of restricting access to the content of a bucket:

- **Private** - users need the AWS credentials to access that file (in the same way as shown in your answer)
- **Public** - everybody can access the content of the bucket (https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myFolder/myFile.jpg)

If you want other users to access the image (for example by providing a URL for your website), you should mark the bucket as public.

DO NOT post the url with your AWS credentials anywhere!!!

Comment: Good to know thank you for reaching out. I do not want users to be able to access other files in the bucket. Do you think encrypting the file names will be enough to ensure that users cannot access other files in the bucket if I make it public? I will look into other ways of displaying that image since it sounds like this could be a security risk.

Comment: Unfortunately, if a bucket is public, it means that all the files in it are public as well. You could potentially have a temporary public bucket to handle the show functionality and then move the image to some other private bucket (but the image will obviously) stop being visible the the user.

Comment: Alternatively, you could specify a whitelist of IP addresses to have access to your bucket but keep in mind that the policy specified over a bucket is applied to all its content.

Comment: Just to make sth clear: when generating an URL that has "AWSAccessKeyId" as a parameter (this is called pre-signed url) the key included is a randomly generated temporary access key. Pre-signed urls are safe to use to share files for example, and won't give access to your whole bucket. See Matt Houser's answer